# Outbound change sets missing after migration to Hyperforce?

Tags: sandbox, change-set, hyperforce

Past weekend my main developer sandbox was migrated to Hyperforce.

Everything appeared to be OK, until I wanted to add something to an outbound change set. They were all gone. In the documentation re. Hyperforce migration, I had missed this apparently.

I checked another sandbox, that also used to contain an open change set. Also gone.

Any way to get them back? Was this to be expected?

Comment: Same happened to me today after the migration that happened during the weekend. Don't think this was documented anywhere, perhaps it's just a metter of time before they get migrated or at least that's what I'm hoping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem.

Salesforce support told me that there's a known bug since April 2023, that makes outbound changesets be deleted when migrating a sandbox to hyperforce:
https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000iwXXGAA2/outbound-change-sets-are-missing-from-sandbox-post-hyperforce-migration

I really hope there will be away to get the changesets back...
Applying migrations to servers, without making backup saves, while a know bug on said migrations has been signaled for a few month is beyond amateurism.

Comment: Thanks. No, the known issue is quite clear: those change sets are gone. It is very disappointing that this issue is known since April and Salesforce does not mention it in the Hyperforce migration documentation. I had four big change sets in two sandboxes and it will take me a lot of time to recreate them.